# Latest visited module not working correct

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Need help with latest visited users.

The problem is that if I visit the ad two or three times then the latest visited module shows the same ad three or more as shown in the picture. I need that the ad I visited only appear on top once and that only the date and position change but not duplicate.

[The picture: 2 first visited is same (dublicated)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fXxEL.png)

MYSQL:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `class_latest_visited_ads`;
CREATE TABLE `class_latest_visited_ads` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ad_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `idx_id` (`id`),
  KEY `idx_ad_id` (`ad_id`),
  KEY `idx_date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;

INSERT INTO class_latest_visited_ads VALUES 
('363', '25', '2021-03-05 09:21:23'),
('363', '73', '2021-03-05 09:21:44'),
('363', '60', '2021-03-05 09:21:55'),
('363', '48', '2021-03-05 09:22:03'),
('363', '39', '2021-03-05 09:22:27'),
('363', '65', '2021-03-05 09:24:15'),
('364', '73', '2021-03-05 10:12:07'),
('363', '69', '2021-03-05 10:57:34'),
('365', '56', '2021-03-05 11:20:48'),
('366', '56', '2021-03-05 15:48:53'),
('367', '56', '2021-03-05 20:09:40'),
('368', '56', '2021-03-06 13:29:34'),
('368', '54', '2021-03-06 15:38:10'),
('400', '70', '2021-03-14 22:24:20');
```

CODE:

```
function getLatestVisited($where_str, $page, $no_per_page) {

    
    if(isset($_COOKIE['ox_latest_visited_id']) && $_COOKIE['ox_latest_visited_id']) { 
        $lv_id = $_COOKIE['ox_latest_visited_id'];
    }
    
    global $settings, $ads_settings, $config_table_prefix;
    
    $locations_str="";
    if($settings['enable_locations'])
        $locations_str = locations::makeQueryStr();

    $listing = new listings();
    $start=($page-1)*$no_per_page;
    $where = " where ".TABLE_ADS.".active = 1";
    $where .= $where_str.$locations_str;
    $order_by_str = "order by ".$config_table_prefix."latest_visited_ads.`date`";
    
    $join = "right join `".$config_table_prefix."latest_visited_ads` on ".$config_table_prefix."ads.id = ".$config_table_prefix."latest_visited_ads.ad_id";
    
    $result=$listing->getShortListings($where,$order_by_str,'desc',$start, $no_per_page, '', '', $join);
    return $result;

}
```

Comment: I would look into [MySQL SELECT DISTINCT](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-distinct.aspx) which could be used to eliminate the same ad from being selected more than once